# Gaussian Elimination - Conceptual meaning of a row of zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I'm in linear algebra and am struggling with this concept.

If I had a matrix like so:

```
|1 0 0 4|
|0 1 0 5|
|0 0 0 0|
```

Would my solution be x=4, y=5, and z can be any number?

Furthermore, what if I had a matrix like so:

```
|1 0 3 8|
|0 1 1 4|
|0 0 0 0|
```

Does this also mean z HAS to be my free variable, or could X OR Y be a free variable as well? I can't seem to wrap my head around what would be allowed to be my free variables in this example.

I'd appreciate some clarification/suggestions - especially on what can be allowed as a free variable in that second matrix.

EDIT:

What about a matrix like this:
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&2&8\\0&1&1&1&4\\0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Could the variable in column 1 be free?

Comment: The non-free variables  correspond to the columns  with a pivot.

Comment: @Bernard - but why? Why is it like that? In my second example, a youtube video explained that even though Z is a free variable, you could instead choose to make x be a free variable and solve to find what y and z is.

Comment: It is only for convenience. Makes easier computations.

Comment: That kind of makes sense - So would it be possible for in the second example, to let x be the free variable and then solve for y and z?

Comment: Yes, absolutely ‘fre variable’ is not an intrinsic property. Depending on the way to make row reduction, you can obtain other pivots anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case $z$ is the only variable that can be chosen as free.

For the second system, the solutions have the form
\begin{cases} x+3z=8 \\ y+z=4 \end{cases}
and $z$ can be chosen as the free variable, but also $x$ or $y$ can.

Indeed, if we solve for $z$, we have $z=(8-x)/3$ and therefore
$$
y=4-z=4-\frac{8-x}{3}=\frac{4+x}{3}
$$
Try for $y$ as free.

What is the difference? In both systems, the third column is a linear combination of the first two columns. But in the second system any of the first three columns is a linear combination of the other two, which is not the case for the first system.

Comment: is there any easy way to conceptualize what a row of zeros truly means? what does it mean in terms of those lines, visually in my head?

Comment: @IsabelleKreienbrink The row of zeros means just that an equation is a linear combination of others, so it is redundant. It has no bearing with free variables.

Comment: Okay so the row of zeros doesn't specify what variable should be free in my problem. It simply states that the use of a third equation is redundant, because it ended up being a duplicate of another equation in the problem - so that means the row of zeros suggests there has to be ONE free variable - but it doesn't specify WHICH variable to use as free - I can pick which one

Comment: if that is incorrect please correct me

Comment: @IsabelleKreienbrink If you are talking about systems with as many equations as unknowns, then it's right. Of course provided that the system has a solution to begin with. You might get \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} and the system would have no solution, despite the row of zeros.

Comment: I edited my question and added a new matrix - would you mind giving me some input?

Comment: @IsabelleKreienbrink The RREF is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&2&1&4\\0&1&1&1&4\\0&0&0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, meaning that, for instance, $c_3=2c_1+c_2$, so that $c_1=(c_3-c_2)/2$. So, yes, the first variable can be taken as free.